# Drawing a line of ones on a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, line

I have a matrix `m = zeros(1000, 1000)`. Within this matrix I want to draw an estimate of the line which passes through 2 points from my matrix. Let's say `x = [122 455];` and `y = [500 500];`.

How can I do this in Matlab? Are there any predefined functions to do this? I am using Matlab 2012b.

Comment: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm.  I don't know if there are any predefined functions either intrinsic or available on File Exchange, you can google for those as easily as I can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll denote the two endpoints as `p1` and `p2` because I'm planning to use `x` and `y` for something else. I'm also assuming that the first coordinate of `p1` and `p2` is *x* and the second is *y*. So here's a rather simple way to do it:

1. Obtain the equation of the line *y* = *ax* + *b*. In MATLAB, this can be done by:

   ```
   x = p1(1):p2(1)
   dx = p2(1) - p1(1);
   dy = p2(2) - p1(2);
   y = round((x - p1(1)) * dy / dx + p1(2));
   ```
2. Convert the values of `x` and `y` to indices of elements in the matrix, and set those elements to 1.

   ```
   idx = sub2ind(size(m), y, x);
   m(idx) = 1;
   ```

#### Example

Here's an example for a small 10-by-10 matrix:

```
%// This is our initial conditon
m = zeros(10);
p1 = [1, 4];
p2 = [5, 7];

%// Ensure the new x-dimension has the largest displacement
[max_delta, ix] = max(abs(p2 - p1));
iy = length(p1) - ix + 1;

%// Draw a line from p1 to p2 on matrix m
x = p1(ix):p2(ix);
y = round((x - p1(ix)) * (p2(iy) - p1(iy)) / (p2(ix) - p1(ix)) + p1(iy));
m(sub2ind(size(m), y, x)) = 1;
m = shiftdim(m, ix > iy); %// Transpose result if necessary
```

The result is:

```
m =
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

**Update:** I have patched this algorithm to work when *dy* > *dx* by treating the dimension with the largest displacement as if it were the x-dimension, and then transposing the result if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of the provided answers work for displacements in `y` greater than in `x` (`dy > dx`).
As pointed out, Bresenham's line algorithm is exactly meant for that.

The matlab file provided [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28190-bresenham-optimized-for-matlab/content/bresenham.m) works similarly than the examples provided in the other answers but covers all the use-cases.
To relate to the previously provided example, the script can be used like this:

```
% initial conditions
m = zeros(10);
p1 = [1, 4];
p2 = [5, 10];% note dy > dx
% use file provided on file exchange
[x y] = bresenham(p1(1),p1(2),p2(1),p2(2));
% replace entries in matrix m
m(sub2ind(size(m), y, x)) = 1;
```

result looks like this:

```
m = 
    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
    0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
    0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: Nice catch about *dy* > *dx*. I've patched my algorithm too, FYI.

Answer (score 1):

For me `(matlab R2013b)` following line did not work, when `p1(1)>p2(2)` (":" can not count backwards):

```
x = p1(1):p2(1);

E.G.:

1:10

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

10:1

Empty matrix: 1-by-0
```

But it worked when I used linspac instead:

```
x = linspace(p1(1), p2(1), abs(p2(1)-p1(1))+1);
```

Comment: If you want to count backwards, use `startpoint:-1:endpoint` instead.